# Loss and mean squared error values not showing during training performance. Not getting predicted line

Tags: regression, tensorflow.js

Currently we are trying to input uber data that includes time of day and ride fare into our TensorFlow.js model. We noticed that when we ran the model on the browser, the points are showing up on our scatterplot but during the training the loss and mean squared error values are not showing up and most importantly our model is not displaying a prediction line.

```js
var userData = [
    {
        "City": "San Francisco",
        "Product_Type": "UberEATS Marketplace",
        "Trip_or_Order_Status": "COMPLETED",
        "Request_Time": "2019-06-16 04:10:44 +0000 UTC",
        "Begin_Trip_Time": "2019-06-16 04:44:40 +0000 UTC",
        "Begin_Trip_Lat": "37.7352602",
        "Begin_Trip_Lng": "-122.4203465",
        "Begin_Trip_Address": "",
        "Dropoff_Time": "2019-06-16 04:44:40 +0000 UTC",
        "Dropoff_Lat": "37.7352602",
        "Dropoff_Lng": "-122.4203465",
        "Dropoff_Address": "",
        "Distance_miles": "2.04",
        "Fare_Amount": "32.34",
        "Fare_Currency": "USD"
    }...]

async function getData() {

    const carsData = await userData;

    // Here we map out the values for each car and filter out the list item that do not have an day or a pay value
    const cleaned = carsData.map(car => ({

        timeInMinutes: calculateMins(car.Request_Time),
        pay_rate: normalizeUberPrice(car.Distance_miles, car.Fare_Amount),
    }))
        .filter(car => (car.day != null && car.pay != null));
    return cleaned;
}

async function run() {

    const data = await getData();


    const values = data.map(d => ({
        x: d.day,
        y: d.pay,
    }));


    tfvis.render.scatterplot(
        { name: 'Horsepower v MPG' },
        { values },
        {
            xAxisDomain: [0, 1600],
            yAxisDomain: [0,10],
            xLabel: 'Day',
            yLabel: 'Pay',
            height: 300
        }
    );

    const model = createModel();
    tfvis.show.modelSummary({ name: 'Model Summary' }, model);

    // Convert the data to a form we can use for training.
    const tensorData = convertToTensor(data);
    console.log(tensorData)
    const { inputs, labels } = tensorData;

    // Train the model  
    await trainModel(model, inputs, labels);
    console.log('Done Training');

    testModel(model, data, tensorData);
}


function createModel() {

    const model = tf.sequential();


    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [1], units: 25, useBias: true }));


    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 50, activation: "sigmoid" }));




    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, useBias: true }));

    return model;
}

function convertToTensor(data) {

    return tf.tidy(() => {


        tf.util.shuffle(data);


        const inputs = data.map(d => d.pay)
        const labels = data.map(d => d.day);

        const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
        const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);

        //Step 3. Normalize the data to the range 0 - 1 using min-max scaling
        const inputMax = inputTensor.max();
        const inputMin = inputTensor.min();
        const labelMax = labelTensor.max();
        const labelMin = labelTensor.min();

        const normalizedInputs = inputTensor.sub(inputMin).div(inputMax.sub(inputMin));
        const normalizedLabels = labelTensor.sub(labelMin).div(labelMax.sub(labelMin));

        return {

            inputs: normalizedInputs,
            labels: normalizedLabels,
            // Return the min/max bounds so we can use them later.
            inputMax,
            inputMin,
            labelMax,
            labelMin,
        }
    });
}

async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {

    model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
        loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
        metrics: ['mse'],
    });

    const batchSize = 32;
    const epochs = 30;



        callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
            { name: 'Training Performance' },
            ['loss', 'mse'],
            { 
                xAxisDomain: [0, 100],
                yAxisDomain: [0,1],
                height: 200, 
                callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
                // ',onBatchEnd'
        ),
        history: tfvis.show.history({
            name: 'History'},
            history,
            ["loss","mse"])

    });
}

function testModel(model, inputData, normalizationData) {
    const { inputMax, inputMin, labelMin, labelMax } = normalizationData;


    const [xs, preds] = tf.tidy(() => {


        const xs = tf.linspace(0, 1, 100);


        const preds = model.predict(xs.reshape([100, 1]));


        const unNormXs = xs
            .mul(inputMax.sub(inputMin))
            .add(inputMin);

        const unNormPreds = preds
            .mul(labelMax.sub(labelMin))
            .add(labelMin);

        return [unNormXs.dataSync(), unNormPreds.dataSync()];
    });


    const predictedPoints = Array.from(xs).map((val, i) => {
        return { x: val, y: preds[i] }
    });

    const originalPoints = inputData.map(d => ({
        x: d.pay, y: d.day,
    }));
    console.log("ORIGINAL POINTS:")
    console.log(originalPoints)


    tfvis.render.scatterplot(
        { name: 'Model Predictions vs Original Data' },
        { values: [originalPoints, predictedPoints], series: ['original', 'predicted'] },
        {
            xAxisDomain: [0,10],
            yAxisDomain: [0,1600],
            xLabel: 'Horsepower',
            yLabel: 'MPG',
            height: 1000
        }
    );
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

Basically we want to see a predicted line for our data but were not getting anything back.

It worked when we used data like this:

```js
var userData = [{
          day: 1
          pay: 20
       },...]
```

Comment: Can you please do a snippet using stackblitz.com and then post the URL here ? It will be easier to spot the error and fix it

Comment: Yeah of course https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cepwrd

Answer (score 0):

The data processing is not well performed. Thus, the values used for prediction contain `NaN` and `Infinity`. As a result, the error computed by `model.fit` is NaN and could therefore not be displayed on the chart of `tfjs-vis`.

The filtering

```
.filter(car => (car.day != null && car.pay != null));
```

is not removing NaN and Infinity. Instead, this condition can be used:

```
.filter(car => isFinite(car.pay + car.day) && !isNaN(car.pay + car.day));
```

Though, the `NaN` and `Infinity` are found within the values of `car.day`, here a general filtering is made over `car.pay` and `car.day` - thus the additional operation -  to make sure that these values will not appear anywhere in the cleaned data.

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-x-and-y-with-tfjs-vis) you can see how to display the loss.